# Simulate CryptographicException on MVC-project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a project (SharePoint-Addin), that throws a CryptographicException from time to time on my customers machine. This Exception happens before even entering any Controller-Action.

I want to catch that error, analyze it and react accordingly. (Currently my guess would be this is some kind of token expiration, so I want to simply show the login-page if this happens)

I got the following code:

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _log.Error("ExceptionError occured ");
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            if (exception!=null)
            {
                _log.Error(exception);
                if (exception is CryptographicException)
                {   
                   Response.Redirect(loginPage, true);
                }
            }
       }
```

This will (hopefully) work, but this question is not about the code, but about how to force a CryptographicException.

Can I add an "evil header" to a request so this will fire?

Answer (score 0):

Look here at MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicexception(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void StringConstructor()
{
    // Construct a CryptographicException using a custom error message.
    string errorMessage = ("Unexpected Operation exception.");
    CryptographicException cryptographicException =
        new CryptographicException(errorMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Created a CryptographicException with the " + 
        "following error message: " + errorMessage);
}
```

or just

```
throw new CryptographicException(errorMessage);
```

Comment: The problem is: Once inside my controller, I have my own "global" exception handlings that catch and return any error as a json, so the the global.asax.cs won't be fired

Comment: Which operation in your code would throw an `CryptographicException`?

Comment: None :) This happens before my code is even entered. But to SIMULATE it the way you suggested I would have to put that somewhere. And I cannot do that in Application_start cause I need the cookies/etc. already set to debug the error

Comment: I understand ... let me think about it :)